# Channel Images with EE3

Tags: channel-images

I'm in the process of upgrading a client's website with EE3 and see that a version of Channel Images is available. However the channel images documentation still references the EE2. If there is a channel images EE3 version, how do I install it and are there other changes I should be aware of and is there any documentation for the EE3? I'm hesitant to upgrade my client's site without further instructions as channel images is an important component.

Comment: Have you tried contacting devdemon about this?

Comment: yes, they don't seem to respond

Answer (score 0):

I use both version (for EE2.x and 3.x) on few site and there's not so many difference.. Installation is quick simple and pretty straight forward.  (You got a /system and /themes folder..

Comment: I think you are talking about installation on EE2 when you refer to "(You got a /system and /themes folder..", which I've done many times. However it is a channel images installation on EE3 which I wish to accomplish.

Comment: If you upgrade your Channel Image license to EE3.. you will download the addon and still get a folder with /system and /themes... The system folder looks like system/user/addons/channel_images.. (that reflect the new folder tree of the addons "system").. Then When you go in your Control Panel in Addons Manager, you will see Channel Image ready to install.

Comment: Thanks I will try.. but it still goes back to my original problem, why doesn't devdemon provide this information (and why don't they respond to my inquires about this)?? I'm not dising their product, it is great, I just can't understand, from a marketing perspective, why you would put doubt in a potential customers mind when it comes to making a purchase.